# Azure Policy -for Deny IP ranges for Cache Redis

Tags: azure, redis, policy

Azure Policy -for Deny IP ranges for Cache Redis.
So the use case is - Deny IP ranges apart from those mentioned in the policy while configuring firewall in Redis

Comment: I have obtained the Deny Policy for Firewall IP range for Cache Redis and its working.

Comment: Can someone help on , Getting Audit Policy for Firewall IP address for Cache Redis.
So use case - if any user didn't configure firewall IP address then resource should be Non compatible.

Comment: If you are trying to go from Deny to Audit, you can change the effect to audit. If this is more complicated. Please post the policy you already have

Comment: Thanks Kernley, I worked on that and its completed. Can you Please help me with Deny policy for Function App. USe case: the user should not be allowed to save any other ip address in the networking -other than those mentioned in policy. I tried with 5 aliases but still not working.